# Hide multiple Group By Columns

Tags: 2010, css, grouping

For a list I have 2 group by columns. Via a CEW i have added the following code

```
.ms-gb a:first-child{
    display:block;
    visibility:hidden;
} 
.ms-gb a:link > img {
    display:inline;
    visibility:visible;
    position:relative;
    top:13px;
    right:5px;
} </style>
```

This only hides the first header (Region). I also need to hide the 2nd one (Country).

Can anyone help me with this code?

Comment: This concerns SP10

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [nth-child(x)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) selector.

> .ms-gb a:first-child, .ms-gb a:nth-child(2){
>       display:block;
>       visibility:hidden; }